# What causes session_regenerate_id(true) to return false?

Tags: php, session

```
\Console::log('session_statusxxx',session_status(),ini_get('session.use_trans_sid'));
if(!session_regenerate_id(true)) { // user attempted to log in; create a new session for him
    throw new \Exception("Could not regenerate session ID");
}
\Console::log('session_statusxxx',session_status());
```

I'm hitting that exception -- i.e., `session_regenerate_id` is returning `false`.

Just prior to calling `session_regenerate_id` I can see that `session_status()` is `2` which is `PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE`, and `session.use_trans_sid` is `"0"`.

Shouldn't `session_regenerate_id` destroy the active session and start a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check your implementation of `SessionHandlerInterface` if you're using `session_set_save_handler`. In my case, I was returning the wrong value from a few of the functions. e.g., `read` should return an *empty string* if there's no session, not `false`, `destroy` should return `true` or `false`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of reasons

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/a2d766503aed619493386a9b4ef8190be62b36f7/ext/session/session.c#L2078

They all emit warnings to give more information  try showing these notices / log extra information on why it failed.

Comment: I wasn't seeing any errors, but thank you for linking to the source!